# What's the best way to create an LDAP connection to an OpenLDAP server using ldapjs?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm getting an error when attempting to create a client connection to an OpenLDAP server.  The error message isn't helpful. Am I missing something in the OpenLDAP setup or configuration?

```
function createLDAPClient () {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if(client.connected) return resolve();

    client = ldap.createClient({
        url: 'ldap://localhost:389',
        strictDN: false,
        timeout: 10000,
        connectTimeout: 10000
        //disableQueue: true
    });

    client.on('connect', function () {
        // console.log("LDAP connected");
        resolve();
    });

    client.on('error', function (err) {
        // console.log("ldap client error", err);
        // idle timeout
        if(err.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
            return reject();
        }
        reject();
    });

});
```

}

Getting error

```
   { InvalidDnSyntaxError: invalid DN
   at messageCallback (D:\Sites\Hermes\opt\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1419:45)
   at Parser.onMessage (D:\Sites\Hermes\opt\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1089:14)
   at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13)
   at Parser.write (D:\Sites\Hermes\opt\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\messages\parser.js:111:8)
   at Socket.onData (D:\Sites\Hermes\opt\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1076:22)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
   at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
   at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
   at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) lde_message: 'invalid DN', lde_dn: null
```

}

Comment: What part of 'invalid DN' don't you understand? Which line of your code threw this exception? What are `resolve()` and `reject()`?

Comment: The code with the error wasn't included in the OP because it wasn't clear where the error  was happening. I've found it, and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was eluding me because I didn't see where the error was being thrown.  The answer is to solve the username in the bind function shown here:

```
function bind (user) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return createLDAPClient()
        .then(function () {
            //console.log("client should be bound", !client.unbound);
            // client.bind(user.username, user.password, function (err) {
            // console.log("attempting bind", user);
            var ldapuser = user.username;
            if( config.ldap.type == 'OpenLDAP'){
                ldapuser = 'cn=' + user.username + ',' + config.ldap.dc;
            }
            client.bind(ldapuser, user.password, function (err) {
                //console.log("user bind callback, err:", !!err);
                if(err) {
                    // console.log("error type", typeof err, Object.keys(err), err.stack);
                    console.error(err);
                    // bad password
                    if(err.stack.indexOf("InvalidCredentialsError") !== -1) {
                        console.log("bad password", user);
                        reject({
                            msg: 'Invalid credentials - 101'
                        });
                    }
                    reject({
                        msg: 'Error connecting to LDAP server',
                        error: err
                    });
                }
                resolve();
            });
        });
});
```

}